# how to pass FSCalendar data from UIKIT to SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I am a designer and try to develop a to-do list app.
In the app, user select one day in calendar, it will to shows to-do list of selected day.
But how can i pass selected date from FSCalendar(UIKIT) to to-do list(SwiftUI)?

Thanks so much!

My app demo in github:
https://github.com/ElvishR/FSCalendar-To-Do-List-Test.git

Content View:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class UserData: ObservableObject{
    @Published var name = "Helsdfsflo"
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userData = UserData()
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(userData.name)
        Button(action:{
            print(self.userData.name)
        }){
            Text(" click to show the selected date")
        }
        CalendarModuleView()
            .frame(width: .infinity, height: 300.0, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

Calendar View

```
import SwiftUI
import FSCalendar

class CalendarModule: UIViewController, FSCalendarDelegate {
    
    var calendar = FSCalendar()
    var formatter = DateFormatter()
    var SelectedDate = ""
    
    let integration = UserData()
    


    fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        calendar.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        initCalendar()
        view.addSubview(calendar)
    }
    
    private func initCalendar() {
        calendar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 300.0)
        calendar.appearance.todayColor = UIColor.systemGreen   
        calendar.appearance.selectionColor = UIColor.systemBlue
    }
    
    //selected day
        func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition){
       // Do the same inside this function and you should be fine
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        SelectedDate = formatter.string(from: date)
        ContentView().userData.name = formatter.string(from: date)
        print(ContentView().userData.name)
        print("calendar did select date \(self.formatter.string(from: date))")
        
      
    }
    
    func calendar(calendar: FSCalendar!, didSelectDate date: NSDate!) {
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        SelectedDate = formatter.string(from: date as Date)
        print("(self.formatter.string(from: date))")
    }
   
}
```

APP Screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEd7c.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `UIViewRepresentable` protocol for bind UIView class with SwiftUI.
Here is a demo:

```
struct CalendarModuleView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var selectedDate: Date?
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> FSCalendar {
        let calendar = FSCalendar()
        calendar.delegate = context.coordinator
        calendar.appearance.todayColor = UIColor.systemGreen
        calendar.appearance.selectionColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        return calendar
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: FSCalendar, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, FSCalendarDelegate {
        
        var parent: CalendarModuleView
        
        init(_ calender: CalendarModuleView) {
            self.parent = calender
        }
        
        func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
            self.parent.selectedDate = date
        }
    }
}
```

Your ContentView

```
class UserData: ObservableObject{
    @Published var name = "Helsdfsflo"
    @Published var date: Date?
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var userData = UserData()
    
    static let taskDateFormat: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(userData.name)
        if userData.date != nil {
            Text("Task due date: \(userData.date!, formatter: Self.taskDateFormat)")
        }
        
        Button(action:{
            print(self.userData.name)
        }){
            Text(" click to show the selected date")
        }
        CalendarModuleView(selectedDate: $userData.date)
            .frame(height: 300.0, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```